# OpenCV: fastNlMeansDenoising function for 16 bits grayscale image - <built-in function fastNlMeansDenoising> "returned NULL without setting an error"

Tags: python, opencv

I want to remove the noise, for this I am using the function on a **grayscale image in 16 bits**. I code this:

```
list_1 = []
for img in np.copy(imgs_exemple_16):
    val = 2**16//np.max(img)
    img *= val
    img = clahe.apply(img)
    list_1.append(cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img,3,normType = cv2.NORM_L1))
# Show
visualize_hor(list_1, idx)
```

However, when I run it I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-61beef5ef74c> in <module>
      5     img *= val
      6     img = clahe.apply(img)
----> 7     list_1.append(cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img,{3},normType = cv2.NORM_L1))
      8 # Show
      9 visualize_hor(list_1, idx)

SystemError:

 <built-in function fastNlMeansDenoising> returned NULL without setting an error
```

I don't understand, I am applying the definition *fastNlMeansDenoising() [3/3]* of the doc https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d79/group__photo__denoise.html#ga4c6b0031f56ea3f98f768881279ffe93, so what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is type and value of `val`? Maybe line 5 does mess up variable type or max value?

Comment: It's `numpy.int64`. But the result image is still `dtype=uint16`, so `val` didn't change something.